# Context overrites my localStorage on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have context setup in my project. It's a todo list. And when i setup the context it's an empty array.

Everytime i submit a todo item it is set in localStorage. Now when i refresh the page i'm setting the localStorage to the empty array of the context and it overrides what i had in localStorage.

Horrible explanation but i hope you get the gist. I'll upload some code below.

Context:

```
import React from "react";

export const TodoContext = React.createContext();

export function TodoComponent({ children }) {
  const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={[todoItems, setTodoItems]}>
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Form:

```
function Form() {
  const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = useContext(TodoContext);
  const [todoInput, setTodoInput] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const localTodoItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    setTodoItems(localTodoItems);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todoItems));
  }, [todoItems]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (todoInput.length >= 1) {
      setTodoItems([
        ...todoItems,
        { id: todoItems.length + 1, name: todoInput },
      ]);

      setTodoInput("");
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormWrapper>
        <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name=""
            id=""
            placeholder="Todo"
            value={todoInput}
            onChange={(e) => setTodoInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen" />
        </form>
      </FormWrapper>
    </>
  );
}
```

List:

```
function List() {
  const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = useContext(TodoContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const localTodoItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));

    setTodoItems(localTodoItems);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todoItems));
  }, [todoItems]);

  const deleteButton = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newArray = todoItems.filter((item) => {
      if (item.id !== id) {
        return item;
      }
    });
    setTodoItems(newArray);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ListWrapper>
        <ul className="list">
          {todoItems?.map((item) => {
            return (
              <>
                <li className="list__item" key={item.id}>
                  <div className="todo">
                    <span className="todo__label">{item.name}</span>
                    <button
                      className="todo__delete"
                      onClick={(e) => deleteButton(e, item.id)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </ListWrapper>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You dont't need to read from localStorage on every component. Try to move the effect that reads the localStorage on the TodoComponent.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. The list component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to recreate and fix the problem. The problem was that the TODOComponent initialized the todoItems to []: `const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = React.useState([]);` which caused the Form and List components to react to the state change and set the localstorage to an empty array.

Updated initialization:

```
export function TodoComponent({ children }) {
const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = React.useState(getTodoItems());

  function getTodoItems() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
  }

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ todoItems, setTodoItems }}>
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The Form and List components also performs extra work. So by only letting the  Form component be the "producer" and the List being the "Consumer" the program can avoid unnecessary work.

Form:

```
function Form() {
  const { todoItems, setTodoItems } = useContext(TodoContext);
  const [todoInput, setTodoInput] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todoItems));
  }, [todoItems]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (todoInput.length >= 1) {
      setTodoItems([
        ...todoItems,
        { id: todoItems.length + 1, name: todoInput },
      ]);

      setTodoInput("");
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name=""
          id=""
          placeholder="Todo"
          value={todoInput}
          onChange={(e) => setTodoInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

List:

```
function List() {
  const { todoItems, setTodoItems } = useContext(TodoContext);

  const deleteButton = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newArray = todoItems.filter((item) => {
      if (item.id !== id) {
        return item;
      }
    });
    setTodoItems(newArray);
  };

  if (!todoItems.length) {
    return <div>No items</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ul className="list">
        {todoItems?.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li className="list__item" key={index}>
              <div className="todo" key={item.key}>
                <span className="todo__label">{item.name}</span>
                <button
                  className="todo__delete"
                  onClick={(e) => deleteButton(e, item.id)}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Sorry, it did not work for me. I still lose all todo's on refresh, i can send you the github code if you'd like

Comment: I'm working with NextJS by the way. When i add your solution it tells me that LocalStorage is not defined

Comment: Okei, i can take a look at it

Comment: You where right! I have found out that the reason it doesnt work for me is because i'm using NextJS. When i use create react app it works fine. It probably has something to do with serverside rendering in NextJS. Which i'm not really familiar with. Thanks a bunch anyway!